# ViewController turns blank when jumping between tabs IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have uiViewControllers embedded in uiNavigationControllers that are driven by a TabBarController. Majority of the time when I move between tabs everythings fine, but at random times when I jump to the first tab the screen goes blank (black). The tabBar is still visible and I'm able to jump to the other two tabs, but the first one remains blank. This has only happened on my iPhone and not in simulator. My appdelegate looks like below code, any ideas?

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

tabBarItem1.title = @"Tab 1";
tabBarItem2.title = @"Tab 2";
tabBarItem3.title = @"Tab 3";

[tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1a.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2a.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem2 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2a.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem3 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3a.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:83/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:83/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[UINavigationBar appearance].titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};

UINavigationController *firstVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
UINavigationController *secondVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
UINavigationController *thirdVCnav = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];

MyFirstVC *oneVC = [[firstVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
oneVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

MySecondVC *twoVC = [[secondVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
twoVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

MyThirdVC *thirdVC = [[thirdVCnav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
thirdVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

From another forum I received a tip to check if I'm using a nib where the view controller setup is preconfigured.
I did have a nib reference in a viewcontroller since I removed it the issue hasn't occured, but since random/rare issue I'll monitor and update if issue comes back.